# How to change the build path when use command xcodebuild

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ6md.jpg)

when I use command `xcodebuild` to build a workspace, the default path is:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BantingAssistant-egoztalzcreabohfvgozqfhfvopa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
```

I want to change the path, or get the path in shell.

Answer (score 0):

The exportPath can be specified on the command-line. It requires that the archive path also be specified. The archive path is the location of the .xcarchive file. The export path is the destination for the IPA file.

```
xcodebuild -archivePath $(YOUR_PATH) -exportPath $(YOUR_PATH/YOUR_FILE.ipa)
```

Please see

```
man xcodebuild
```

for the full list of command-line path options.

Comment: thank you ,i want set path to get the .app,so i can  use the commans xrun to export the .ipa。